# Retag questions [visual] [basic] -> [vb]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retag-request

[Some Visual Basic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual+basic) are tagged with [visual] and [basic], which just seems to be a mistake. Should we retag those questions to [vb]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we'll have to go through those so that the versioning gets done right, i.e. vb6, vb5, vba, etc.  I certainly agree we don't need that pair of tags on anything.

**EDIT:** OK, I took care of them all.